# FileTransfer only partially download files

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer, ngcordova

Tried to download file using [Filetransfer Cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) for android but all the files are downloaded partially. It will download just a random number of Bytes (~ 1-1.5 MB) and then fire a success download event.
This is the code:

```
var uri = encodeURI('http://192.168.1.5:3000/downloads/' + $scope.file.filename);
var trustHost = true;
var options = {};
var fileName = "thisIsAFile.ext";
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {})
   .then(function(){
      var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
      fileTransfer.download(
      uri,
      "file://mnt/sdcard/Download/" + fileName,
          function(entry) {
              $ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: "success".toUpperCase(),
                  template: JSON.stringify(entry)
              })
          },
          function(error) {
              console.log("download error source " + error.source);
              console.log("download error target " + error.target);
          },
      trustHost, options);
 });
```

I can easily download files with a browser from the server (either web or mobile version).

The logcat doesn't help or the success object inspection.

All the permissions are set in `res/xml/config.xml` and everything looks fine in `AndroidManifest.xml`

I've also tried different file paths and I've tried with `cordova.file.*` and fileSystem.root

I'm baffled.

I'm using Ionic and ngCordova.
The FileTransfer is file-transfer 0.4.3
I've tried the 0.5 version and it gives me a persistent code 3 error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you have a detailed error?

Comment: It doesn't give me any error but the success object is `{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"immagino.jpg","fullPath":"/Download/immagino.jpg","filesystem":"<FileSystem: persistent>","nativeURL":"file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/immagino.jpg"}`.

The file is 1.6 MB and it has downloaded only 1.2 MB

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by using the `res.sendFile()` - i'm using node.js - on server-side. I'm not sure why but it seems that the static url - the resource address - need also a response containing the file data.
I hope this could be helpful.